# Soft High pitched whine in the background at all times. UbuntuStudio 20.04 on alienware

Tags: sound

I'm getting a soft high pitched whine coming out of my speakers, while my computer is active. It's a B, 2 octaves above middle C, and it's a sawtooth wave.

Audio out is patched to my stereo receiver via RCA cables, and the whine is audible from its speakers, only when outputting the computer)

I am running UbuntuStudio 20.04, lowlatency, specifically for the purpose of doing (hobby) music production. (Installed as Kubuntu initially, then I ran the UbuntuStudio installer to get the audio setup, per recommendation on the UbuntuStudio site.)

Running it as dual boot with windows 10, running on a separate drive. When I run windows, there is no audio whine.

I'm using Studio Controls, which configures a pulse_out  which can be configured to to run pulseaudio through Jack. I have to *manually* configure that  output of Pulseaudio to jack in QJackCtrl each time I start up the OS, so when the computer starts, Jack controls the audio outs. However, the whine begins BEFORE I do this pulse configuration -- even though no other system sounds are audible. So my whine seems to be coming from Jack.

hardware: Alienware aurora-r9, nvidia graphics
kernel 5.4.0-48-lowlatency #52-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 10 11:51:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lshw

```
H/W path                 Device      Class          Description
===============================================================
                                     system         Alienware Aurora R9 (0961)
/0                                   bus            0T76PD
/0/0                                 memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/27                                memory         32GiB System Memory
/0/27/0                              memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/27/1                              memory         16GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 
/0/27/2                              memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/27/3                              memory         16GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 
/0/2e                                memory         512KiB L1 cache
/0/2f                                memory         2MiB L2 cache
/0/30                                memory         12MiB L3 cache
/0/31                                processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700 CP
/0/100                               bridge         8th Gen Core 8-core Desktop 
/0/100/1                             bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6
/0/100/1/0                           display        TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti]
/0/100/1/0.1                         multimedia     TU116 High Definition Audio 
/0/100/1/0.2                         bus            TU116 USB 3.1 Host Controlle
/0/100/1/0.2/0           usb3        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1/0.2/1           usb4        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1/0.3                         bus            TU116 [GeForce GTX 1650 SUPE
/0/100/1.1                           bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6
/0/100/2                             display        UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop 9 
/0/100/8                             generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500
/0/100/14                            bus            200 Series/Z370 Chipset Fami
/0/100/14/0              usb1        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1                        bus            USB2734
/0/100/14/0/1/5                      input          Hub Controller
/0/100/14/0/2                        input          USB-HID Keyboard
/0/100/14/0/3                        multimedia     USB AUDIO  CODEC
/0/100/14/0/4                        input          AW-ELC
/0/100/14/0/5                        input          USB Trackball
/0/100/14/0/6                        input          2.4G Wireless Mouse
/0/100/14/0/8                        communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/0/a                        multimedia     Lihappe8 Webcam L0485A2SP
/0/100/14/0/e                        storage        Dell DVD+/-RW Drive DW316
/0/100/14/1              usb2        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/16                            communication  200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17                scsi0       storage        200 Series PCH SATA controll
/0/100/17/0              /dev/sdb    disk           1TB ST1000DM010-2EP1
/0/100/17/0/1            /dev/sdb1   volume         127MiB reserved partition
/0/100/17/0/2            /dev/sdb2   volume         931GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/17/1              /dev/sdc    disk           500GB CT500MX500SSD1
/0/100/17/1/1                        volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/17/1/2            /dev/sdc2   volume         465GiB LVM Physical Volume
/0/100/1b                            bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express R
/0/100/1b/0                          storage        Micron Technology Inc
/0/100/1c                            bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express R
/0/100/1c/0                          bus            ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Control
/0/100/1c/0/0            usb5        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c/0/1            usb6        bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c/0/1/1          scsi4       storage        d2 Quadra USB 3.0
/0/100/1c/0/1/1/0.0.0    /dev/sda    disk           2TB d2 Quadra v3C
/0/100/1c/0/1/1/0.0.0/1  /dev/sda1   volume         1862GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1c.2                          bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express R
/0/100/1c.2/0            wlp5s0      network        QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Ne
/0/100/1c.3                          bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express R
/0/100/1c.3/0            enp6s0      network        Killer E2500 Gigabit Etherne
/0/100/1d                            bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express R
/0/100/1e                            generic        200 Series/Z370 Chipset Fami
/0/100/1f                            bridge         Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Contro
/0/100/1f.2                          memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                          multimedia     200 Series PCH HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4                          bus            200 Series/Z370 Chipset Fami
/0/1                                 system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/2                                 system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/3                                 communication  PnP device PNP0501
/0/4                                 system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/5                                 system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/6                                 generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/7                                 system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/8                                 system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/9                                 system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/a                                 system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/b                     scsi5       storage        
/0/b/0.0.0               /dev/cdrom  disk           DVD+/-RW DW316
```

Comment: A " whine" where? Through the audio output, or from the PC itself? What does "some apps require the volume to be turned higher" have to do with it?

Comment: yes -- the whine is coming through the computer's audio output. My audio output goes to a stereo component receiver and the whine is audible through the speakers attached to that (it's not audible when I switch the receiver to monitor any other devices -- i.e. turntable / cassette deck -- only for computer)

new nuance -- the whine starts occurring BEFORE I hook up pulse to jack. when I start up, I have to manually connect pulseaudio to jack before I start hearing regular system sounds. However the whine is ALREADY present, before I do this.

Comment: The detail about turning the volume up is probably not very useful, but when I have the volume at a normal level on startup, I don't hear the whine. But then some apps or clips encountered on the internet are softer, so the volume gets turned up and the whine is obvious.

Further detail, the whine is not present when I boot into Windows, only in Ubuntustudio.

Comment: Ok, you should add all that to your initial post, and some info about what audio interface you're using might be useful. Adding UbuntuStudio on top of an existing installation is not the same as installing UbuntuStudio from the beginning, so something might have gone wrong there. Usually it should not be necessary to use JACK just to output system sounds. I would play around with the settings in pavucontrol. If you have two audio interfaces, like it seems you have, it might use the wrong one by default.

Comment: OK thanks, I made some edits. the UbuntuStudio site tells you to install an Ubuntu flavor then run the installer, as if the product is essentially the same. My problem seems to be with Jack, since the whine starts BEFORE pulseaudio is audible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution out of left field. If you have an illuminated keyboard with multiple illumination levels (I have a Logitech K740) the intermediate illumination levels cause the speakers to hum, at least on my setup. The problem has nothing to do with the OS - it happens in both Ubuntu and Windows on my dual boot system. The sound only with the backlight full on or full off.

It's a long shot, but it's an easy test.

Comment: interesting. I do have an illuminating keyboard, but I don't believe it supports multiple levels. I unplugged it and the whine did not cease.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an unshielded wire?  Computers are an awful source of interference for unshielded wires.
I run a Mixer, with a Mic on stand and wireless and I use shielded wires everywhere.

Comment: you mean connecting my computer to the stereo receiver? The thing here is I do not get the same sound when I boot the same machine into windows. It only happens when I boot into ubuntu.

Comment: No  I run a Audio Mixer, I have 3 sets of Wireless Lavaliere Mics, and one wired and the out from that mixer to the Computer is Shielded.  But when I am On Linux Mint, unsure about Ubuntu Studio, I also hear a high pitched sound, but Windows 10 does not do it, and I have not figured out why yet.  I suspect it has to do with the way Ubuntu  has the drivers configured for the computer, given time I will figure this out.  The best place to the shielded wire is a Music shop

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that your mixer outputs to the computer, producing a whine, and you fixed it by getting shielded wires to connect the mixer audio out to the computer audio input. My situation is the computer output goes from the line out to  the "tape recorder" in of the stereo receiver (it has the old trad'l Tuner/CD/Phono/Tape/VCR inputs, all RCA ins). So my computer output produces the whine, from UbuntuStudio only. I could test it with all my inputs removed to see if any of them introduced the whine, I haven't tried that.